# Ability Scores bonus spells and metamagic feats

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ability-scores, metamagic

First of all, I'm not asking this question to solve an issue. My GM and I both agree on the fact this *should* not be possible to avoid any game breaking mechanics.

However, we couldn't find any rules on this matter on the wiki we're using (we're not native English speakers), I asked Google only to find out people saying "I think you can't" without any source, or leave the subject and speak about *learning* spells and not using already learnt ones.

My mage is currently level 3 with 24 intelligence, as far as I know he cannot learn 3rd level spells. Nonetheless, he has access to two bonus 3rd level slots. **What's stopping him to learn 2nd level and fuse with any +1 metamagic feat (such as Intensified Spell)? Same with 1st level spells and +2 megamagic feat.**

Please, use official rules based evidence. Thank you and have a good day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only get bonus spells [if you're of a high enough level to cast the spells normally:](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/gettingStarted.html#bonus-spells-per-day)

> The ability that governs bonus spells depends on what type of spellcaster your character is: Intelligence for wizards; Wisdom for clerics, druids, and rangers; and Charisma for bards, paladins, and sorcerers. **In addition to having a high ability score, a spellcaster must be of a high enough class level to be able to cast spells of a given spell level.**

Thus, once you hit class level 5th, your 24 Intelligence *will* grant you bonus spells, but it will not do so during class levels 1st through 4th.

Paizo also has [a FAQ entry](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9o91) about this, in case there's any doubt regarding how this works.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. So an 2nd spell with a +1 megamagic feat counts as a 3nd level spells according to rules?

Comment: And, in case there's any doubt as to the intent of the bolded text, Pathfinder's publishers have an entry in their FAQ dedicated to this: http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9o91

Comment: A 2nd-level spell with a +1 metamagic must be prepared in or cast out of a 3rd-level spell slot, which you currently do not have.

Comment: @GuillaumeC. It *uses a 3rd-level slot or spell per day*. It does not count as being able to cast spells of that level for the purpose of gaining bonus spells from a high ability score, qualifying for prestige classes, or any other purpose.

Comment: @mech good find. Added it to the answer.